# wso2 data mapper unable to parse the json

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-esb

So I was trying to make a map for this json response but I am getting an error when I use the data mapper and load the json file from the file system.

I use the data mapper mediator to map it. Maybe there is another way to do this?

> "Error occurred while opening file."
>
> Reason: File content cannot be parsed.

here is the json

```
{
    movie: [{
        omdbapi: {
            title: "The Legend of Tarzan",
            id: "tt0918940",
            runtime: "109 min",
            year: 2016,
            originaltitle: "The Legend of Tarzan",
            plot: "Tarzan, having acclimated to life in London, is called back to his former home in the jungle to investigate the activities at a mining encampment.",
            rating: "PG-13",
            genre: "Action, Adventure",
            director: "David Yates",
            thumb: "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzY3OTI0OTcyMF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjkxNTAwOTE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
        }
    }, {
        moviedbapi: {
            adult: false,
            backdrop_path: "/75GFqrnHMKqkcNZ2wWefWXfqtMV.jpg",
            belongs_to_collection: null,
            budget: 180000000,
            genres: [{
                name: "Action",
                id: 28
            }, {
                name: "Adventure",
                id: 12
            }],
            homepage: "http://legendoftarzan.com",
            id: 258489,
            imdb_id: "tt0918940",
            original_language: "en",
            original_title: "The Legend of Tarzan",
            overview: "Tarzan, having acclimated to life in London, is called back to his former home in the jungle to investigate the activities at a mining encampment.",
            popularity: 34.036008,
            poster_path: "/6FxOPJ9Ysilpq0IgkrMJ7PubFhq.jpg",
            production_companies: [{
                name: "Dark Horse Entertainment",
                id: 552
            }, {
                name: "Jerry Weintraub Productions",
                id: 2596
            }],
            release_date: "2016-06-29",
            revenue: 0,
            runtime: 109,
            spoken_languages: {
                name: "English",
                iso_639_1: "en"
            },
            status: "Released",
            tagline: "Human. Nature.",
            title: "The Legend of Tarzan",
            video: false,
            vote_average: 4.6,
            vote_count: 501
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample schema can be imported without an issue in new WSO2 ESB Tooling 5.0.0 Beta2. You can get released version from : https://github.com/wso2/devstudio-tooling-esb/releases/tag/v5.0.0-BETA2

There has been a significant amount of improvements done to Data Mapper mediator and tooling and it's best if you use the latest version.

[image]

Comment: I was using their ALPHA version so that is why. huh?

Comment: Yes. Beta2 version has resolved a lot of issues as above and includes a lot of improvements. :)